# Laravel: How to use pessimistic locking with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I saw most of examples in Pessimistic locking by using query builder, like in below.

```
DB::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->lockForUpdate()->get();
```

How can I use Pessimistic locking with Eloquent in laravel?

Comment: use transaction.. well, you can dig in stackoverflow for examples.. and no, i'm not the one downvote you..

Comment: Did you test it with eloquent `User::where('votes', '>', 100)->lockForUpdate()->get();` what did you get ??

Answer (score 0):

To do this you simply need to use the model as normal. As stated in Maraboc's comment just use the Eloquent model and set filters and call lockForUpdate before the get().

Example: `User::where('votes', '>', 100)->lockForUpdate()->get();`