# How to lock table with Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, locking, innodb

I want to lock a table inside a transaction. Something like this:

```
  DB::transaction(function (){
    DB::statement('LOCK TABLES important_table WRITE');
    //....
  });
```

However, the line `DB::statement('LOCK TABLES important_table WRITE');` always triggers the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. (SQL: LOCK TABLES
>   officeSeal WRITE)

How can I lock the table in Laravel?

Comment: I wonder why you would need to lock a InnoDB table.. You really want InnoDB to behave like MyISAM? Besides using a TRANSACTION will lock the records needed.

Comment: @RaymondNijland the reason why I need to lock a complete table can be found https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223608/using-transactions-without-select-for-update/223609 (see answer + comment)

Comment: Besides TRANSACTIONS in MySQL also supports transaction [isolation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) also might be worth studing..

Comment: @RaymondNijland not sure if I understood you correctly - are you suggesting to copy the computed gaps in a temporary table? Because I compute the gaps in step 1, not in step 3. Sorry I am alittle confused. I read the section about transaction isolation.

Comment: Do _not_ use `LOCK TABLES` with InnoDB.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One can lock a table in Laravel like this:

`DB::statement(DB::raw('LOCK TABLES important_table WRITE'))`;

However, you should be aware that locking a table is not very performant and row-locking should be used instead if possible.

Comment: To anyone tried this answer but failed, try this: `DB::unprepared('LOCK TABLES important_table WRITE');`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346162/difference-between-laravels-raw-sql-functions

Comment: @尤川豪 what Laravel version are you using? Seems like it should be fixed since 2013 https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/53

Comment: I just want to remind others that `DB::raw` will only generate string. It will not execute sql statement directly.

Comment: so what is row-locking? how to implement it?

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments by other users too, I don't feel certain that a table lock is absolutely the only way out. However, if you insist, you could use Laravel's [Pessimistic Locking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#pessimistic-locking). Namely, `sharedLock()` and `lockForUpdate()` methods, as mentioned in the documentation.

You'd notice that the example in the documentation doesn't use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent), but relies on [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries). However, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46886286/2298301) seems to suggest that it can be done with Eloquent too.

It may also be worthwhile to have a read through [this article](https://medium.com/@aslrousta/pessimistic-vs-optimistic-locking-in-laravel-264ec0b1ba2) which contrasts Pessimistic and Optimistic locking implementations in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

DB::unprepared('LOCK TABLES important_table WRITE');  this one worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('LOCK TABLES the_table WRITE'));
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers, especially if your answer does not contain any explanation

Comment: @NicoHaase It's not duplicate, putting DB::raw in DB::statement makes this answer unique

Comment: Feel free to add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it